# How to find the coordinates of the labels in `dotchart` in R?

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if I could find the coordinates (i.e., x, y) of the **labels** (as circled in blue in the picture below) in a `dotchart` in R?

```
y = rnorm(20)

groups = factor( rep(1:2, times = c(5, 15) ) )

dotchart(y, groups = groups)
```

[image]

**Update:** I'm also asking what is `y` coordinate of the point exactly between double-headed arrow in the picture below (suppose I know the `x` but I want the point to be in between the double-headed arrow, so what is the `y` so I can put the point in the area between the double-headed arrow):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking inside the `dotchart` function, one can see that group labels are written using `mtext`:

```
mtext(glabels, side = 2, line = goffset, at = gpos, adj = 0, 
    col = "red", las = 2, cex = 1)
```

where `gpos` is the vector of positions of the group labels, calculated by:

```
gpos <- rev(cumsum(rev(tapply(groups, groups, length)) + 2) - 1)

#########
1  2 
23 16
```

Below we try to print group labels exactly in the same positions (and red color) of the group labels printed by `dotcharts`:

```
graphics.off()
set.seed(1)
y = rnorm(20)
groups = factor( rep(1:2, times = c(5, 15) ) )
dotchart(y, groups = groups)

glabels <- levels(groups) 
linch <- 0
ginch <- max(strwidth(glabels, "inch"), na.rm = TRUE)
goffset <- 0.4
nmai <- par("mai")
nmai[2L] <- nmai[4L] + max(linch + goffset, ginch) + 0.1
par(mai = nmai)
lheight <- par("csi")
gpos <- rev(cumsum(rev(tapply(groups, groups, length)) + 2) - 1)
ginch <- max(strwidth(glabels, "inch"), na.rm = TRUE)
goffset <- (max(linch + 0.2, ginch, na.rm = TRUE) + 0.1)/lheight
mtext(glabels, side = 2, line = goffset, at = gpos, adj = 0, 
    col = "red", las = 2, cex = 1)
```

[image]

**EDIT.**
Download from this [link](https://pastebin.com/8sVtUb4h) a modified version of `dotchart` and save it in your working directory as `mydotchart.r`

Then type this code:

```
source("mydotchart.r")
set.seed(1)
y = rnorm(20)
groups = factor( rep(1:2, times = c(5, 15) ) )
mydotchart(y, groups = groups)
```

The function `mydotchart.r` gives the following output:

```
$gpos
 1  2 
23 16 

$linepos
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 18 19 20 21 22
```

where `gpos` is the y-position of group labels and `linepos` is the vector of y-positions of the horizontal dotted grey lines.
Using `linepos` it is possibile to calculate the position between the double-headed arrow in the question above.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I appreciate it, Thank you.